# How to replace `abc` to `abc'` in Notepad++ using Regex

Tags: regex, text, replace, notepad++, text-editor

Original text:

```
set    ,     1
note   ,     1
hello  ,     1
```

Expected text:

```
set'    ,     1
note'   ,     1
hello'  ,     1
```

I tried replacing `[a-z]\s` as `'`, but it will lose the last character.

Comment: `(?<=[a-z])\s` does notepad++ support `positive lookbehind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[a-z]` means just one character in the range `a` to `z`, you have to use `[a-z]+`. `+` means one or more characters.

I suggest you use:

```
^([a-z]+)
```

And in the replacement field, write:

```
$1'
```

`^` means the very beginning of the string. `$1` is a variable where you store the matched string inside the parenthesis `()`.

Comment: I agree with you. Still have the problem for replacement. How to keep the original match characters?

Comment: I updated the answer. Sorry for previous incompleteness

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
([a-z])\s
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lE1vT9/1)

Substitution:
`$1'`